# unable to mock collection objects

Tags: java, mockito

How do I mock this particular snippet?

```
Collection<SeoUrlParam> params = getUrlState().getParameters();
```

I have already mocked

```
urlState = mock(UrlState.class);
```

But I am not sure how to mock the params collection of type  which is infact a class

Comment: `when(urlState.getParameters()).thenReturn(/* whatever you want */)`

You can build any number of SeoUrlParam mock objects and then manually add them to a Collection, but there's probably no need to mock the Collection itself.

Comment: thanks.. but I have tried that way only. but the issue is urlState.getParameters() in my actual class expects Collection<SeoUrlParam> in which SeoUrlParam is a class by itself.

Comment: I tried the followign way, but got nullpointer exception:param1 = mock(SeoUrlParam.class);
  param2 = mock(SeoUrlParam.class);
  params.add(param1);
  params.add(param2);

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to mock the collection.  You want somewhat real data to exist in the collection, and let the code operate it from there instead.

Now, with the way your call is laid out, it may be the case that you have two mock objects - one to produce the mock result of `getUrlState()`, and one to actually return a collection from `getParameters()`.

I'm not sure of the type you're using for either of those calls, so I'll wing it.  The principle applies, though.

```
// Assuming you have the appropriate mock for getUrlState defined
SeoUrlParamHolder parameterHolderMock = mock(SeoUrlParamHolder.class);
Collection<SeoUrlParam> dummyData = Collections.singletonList(new SeoUrlParam());

when(urlState.getUrlState()).thenReturn(parameterHolderMock);
when(parameterHolderMock.getParamters()).thenReturn(dummyData);
```

Comment: SeoUrlParamHolder parameterHolderMock = mock(SeoUrlParamHolder.class);I dont have such a class at all.All I have is urlState = mock(UrlState.class);

Comment: Again, I don't know what object is returned from `getUrlState()`.  This was meant as an illustrative example.

Comment: getUrlState() returns the object urlState of class 'UrlState'

Comment: also when we try when(urlState.getParameters()).thenReturn(dummyData); i am getting compilation error :"The method when(Collection) is undefined for ...."

Comment: You're misunderstanding me.  You've got a chained call `getUrlState().getParameters()`.  I don't know what object is used to call `getParameters()` from.  You have to either fill in the blanks so I can better answer your question - otherwise, there's no way I can help you.

Comment: In my original code , the urlState is taken as below:urlState = ((SeoUrlFormatter) getEndecaSeoUrlUtil()
      .getUrlFormatter()).parseRequest(pRequest.getQueryString(),
        pRequest.getRequestURI().replace(getUrlSuffix(), ""),
        pRequest.getCharacterEncoding()); as per your above comment, do you mean to say i should mock each and every get() of this and then form the urlState. then only i wil get getParameters() as desired?

Answer (score 1):

Don't mock collection objects.  Collections themselves don't generally have enough logic in them to make it worthwhile to stub the logic out.

Treat your collections as value objects, and create real collections as needed.  If you want to mock the individual objects inside the collection, that's fine, and a practice that I thoroughly recommend.